A drawing facing you
What do you see below? (Explain your reasoning)

       |                 
       |                 |6
       |                 |
      3\                 |
        \                /
         \              /
         7\            /1
           \          /
             
          
            


           
          4/          \
         9/            \5
         /              \
        /                \
      8/                 |
       |                 |10
       |                 |
       |

Answer: 1?345678910?

Some really creative puzzles you have made of late!

@PDT Thanks, I try to create different types of text format - puzzles because unfortunately I haven't had access to a laptop for many weeks now, so haven't been able to do the puzzles I usually create.

Hmmm I have created most of my puzzles on my phone too without too much of an obstacle I use PowerPoint and ibisPaint X if you are interested

I see...

 EXTREMITIES!

Because these strings resemble...

 ...the arms and legs (i.e. limbs, or extremities) of a person, where the head and body are not shown. If they are indeed facing you then on the left we would see their right arm and right leg, and on the right we see their left arm and left leg. Note then that each chain of dashes is exactly the right length to insert the words RIGHT ARM, RIGHT LEG, LEFT ARM, and LEFT LEG in the anatomically correct corresponding positions.

 If we spell out the words as if radiating outwards from the missing torso, we produce a diagram like this:



 And now if we take the numbered letters in order we produce the extraction E?TREMITIE? (1=E, 3=T, 4=R, 5=E, 6=M, 7=I, 8=T, 9=I, 10=E) where positions 2 and 11 are unclued. The obvious letters to enter here to make a relevant English word are an X and an S, giving us the answer to this puzzle: EXTREMITIES!


+1 The red (and black) person has their arms raised, is excited and is shouting, “Wow! Stiv solved it”. :)

Correct, nice job!
